# Python: Copy sheets from excel workbook and paste into new workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a super beginner and still learning Python.

I have an excel workbook which contains multiple sheets and only want certain sheets to be copied and pasted in a new created worbook and Im having some troubles.

below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('AMT.xlsb', sheet_name=['Roster','LOA'])

# print whole sheet data
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=['Roster','LOA'])
```

I get an error "IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible", none of the sheets from the AMT file are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be converting your frame to a dict - Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('AMT.xlsb', sheet_name='Roster')
df1 = pd.read_excel('AMT.xlsb', sheet_name='LOA')


# print whole sheet data
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Roster", index=False)
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="LOA", index=False)
```

You may still have some clean up after...